# Html/jQuery - Used multi-select jquery ui dropdown but not working proprely

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, multi-select

**Issue:** Appending options to different dropdown instead of multiselect dropdown

I have given all code and used `multiselect()` function but actully option are appending to different new select tag instead of multiselect drop down.

please refer image for actual working of it which is not correct.

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sohampshetty/rTjkr/5268/)

**HTML**

```
<select id="impact-report-type-filter-input" name="impact-report-type-filter-input" multiple='multiple'>
</select>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#impact-report-type-filter-input").multiselect({
        noneSelectedText: 'Select Legends',
        minWidth: 165,
        header: "Select Legend(s)",
    });
    getDropDownOptions()
})



 function getDropDownOptions(filterType) {

    $.ajax({
        'async': false,
        'type':'POST',
        'url':"/" + $("#app").val() + "/reports/getDataforChart"
        'success':function(data) {
            console.log(data)
            var xml = data.xml;
            var filterList = data.filterList;
            alert(Object.prototype.toString.call(filterList));

            for(f in filterList){
                $('#impact-report-type-filter-input').append($('<option>', {
                     value: filterList[f],
                     text:  filterList[f]
                }));
            }
            $("#impact-report-type-filter-input").multiselect("rebuild"); 

            /*var html = '';

            for (var i = 0, len = filterList.length; i < len; ++i) {
                html.join('<option value="' + filterList[i]['value'] + '">' + filterList[i]['label'] + '</option>');
            }           

            $('#impact-report-type-filter-input').append(html);*/

            typeFilterChartID.setXMLData(xml) ;
            var dataPieData = document.getElementById("impact-report-type-filter") ;
            typeFilterChart.render(dataPieData);
          }
    });
}
```

[image]

**Answer: Forgot to refresh** `$("#impact-report-type-filter-input").multiselect("refresh");`

Comment: You have included css of multi select ?

Comment: yes if i havent then dropdown also will not come. am I correct?

Comment: Can you please add your code to jsfiddle so i can review it. Thanks

Comment: i tried but its throwing error multiselect is not function after including js n css too

Comment: okay not an issue. just send me url.

Comment: Just let me know which type of multiselect you want !
if there any image it will be excellent !

Comment: I have attched image that is only i want but issue is its appending options to other dropdown instead of multi-select (select legend) dropdown. i have also attached fiddle plz check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104139/discussion-between-ankit-vadariya-and-soham-shetty).

Comment: Check your code `'url':"/" + $("#app").val() + "/reports/getDataforChart` you forgot `"` maybe thats the issue `'url':"/" + $("#app").val() + "/reports/getDataforChart"`

Comment: While editing it happened mistake i am getting result in sucess

Comment: Thank you all. forgot refreshing dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace `$("#impact-report-type-filter-input").multiselect("rebuild");` to `$("#impact-report-type-filter-input").multiselect("refresh");` in above jQuery `getDropDownOptions(filterType)` function.